# KeyGenerator not available - Java issue

Tags: java, ssl, java-11

So I am doing a small project and getting extremely frusterated. Ive tried inputting different algorithms for the KeyGenerator and different key sizes but with no luck. Could someone please help me out?
If I put simply "AES" - I get ECB Mode can not use IV
and if I put "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING" - I get KeyGenerator not available

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SslServerApplication {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 192;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SecretKey key = generateKey();
        String message = "Hello, Professor Conlan!";

        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(message, key);
        byte[] hash = hash(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Hash: " + bytesToHex(hash));

        boolean verified = verifyChecksum(hash, encrypted, key);
        System.out.println("Checksum verified: " + verified);
    }
    //generates secret key
    private static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }
    //encrypts secret key key
    static byte[] encrypt(String message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    static byte[] hash(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        return md.digest(message);
    }

    private static boolean verifyChecksum(byte[] checksum, byte[] message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        byte[] hash = hash(decrypt(message, key));
        return MessageDigest.isEqual(hash, checksum);
    }
    //decrypts the encrypted secret key
    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(message, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(message, cipher.getBlockSize(), message.length));
    }

    static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssl-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ssl-server</name>
    <description>ssl-server skeleton for CS-305</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory default-value="C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\M7 Folder"/>
                </configuration>
                
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What’s in you pom?

Answer (score 2):

"AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING" is a [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) specification consisting of

- an algorithm name (AES - [Cipher Algorithm Names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#cipher-algorithm-names))
- an algorithm mode (CBC - [Cipher Algorithm Modes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#cipher-algorithm-modes))
- an algorithm padding (PKCS5PADDING - [Cipher Algorithm Paddings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#cipher-algorithm-paddings))

---

For the [`KeyGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html) only the algorithm itself is relevant ([KeyGenerator Algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keygenerator-algorithms)) and you **must** only specify the algorithm when calling `KeyGenerator.getInstance()`.

`KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")` will work for the `KeyGenerator`.

**Note**: For the `Cipher` you **still must use** "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING"! Otherwise you will get a provider-specific [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html):

> A transformation is of the form:
>
> - "algorithm/mode/padding" or
> - "algorithm"
>
> (in the latter case, provider-specific default values for the mode and padding scheme are used).

Comment: I tried using AES and It didn't work. I stated that in the original post

Comment: @Shawn if you want "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING" as the cipher then you must still specify that for the `Cipher` - otherwise you get some provider-specific default values. But "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING" is a cipher specification and you cannot use that to create a key. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Shawn you can't pass the same string to both `KeyGenerator.getInstance` and `Cipher`. They are different strings. `AES` for one, `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same value for the KeyGenerator algorithm and the Cipher algorithm.

These are the legal values of [KeyGenerator algorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyGenerator). Your value of `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` is not among them as Thomas's answer correctly indicates.

```
AES
ARCFOUR
Blowfish
DES
DESede
HmacMD5
HmacSHA1 HmacSHA256 HmacSHA384 HmacSHA512
RC2
```

The following are the [Cipher algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) that must be supported by Java implementations. Your value of `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` will work here (if your code gets far enough.

```
AES/CBC/NoPadding (128)
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (128)
AES/ECB/NoPadding (128)
AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (128)
DES/CBC/NoPadding (56)
DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding (56)
DES/ECB/NoPadding (56)
DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (56)
DESede/CBC/NoPadding (168)
DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding (168)
DESede/ECB/NoPadding (168)
DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding (168)
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding (1024, 2048)
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding (1024, 2048)
```

The following is code that 'works'. Your code has other issues.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SslServerApplication {
    private static final String KEYGENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 192;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SecretKey key = generateKey();
        String message = "Hello, Professor Conlan!";

        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(message, key);
        byte[] hash = hash(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Hash: " + bytesToHex(hash));

        boolean verified = verifyChecksum(hash, encrypted, key);
        System.out.println("Checksum verified: " + verified);
        
        String decrypted =  new String(decrypt(encrypted, key));
        System.out.println("Decrypted messaged: " + decrypted);
       
        
    }
    //generates secret key
    private static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEYGENERATOR_ALGORITHM);
        keyGenerator.init(KEY_SIZE);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }
    //encrypts secret key key
    static byte[] encrypt(String message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    static byte[] hash(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        return md.digest(message);
    }

    private static boolean verifyChecksum(byte[] checksum, byte[] message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        byte[] hash = hash(decrypt(message, key));
        return MessageDigest.isEqual(hash, checksum);
    }
    //decrypts the encrypted secret key
    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(message, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(message, cipher.getBlockSize(), message.length));
    }

    static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```